# Drag to select text in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, copy-paste

I need to be able to select text in a listbox so I'm able to also crtl + c on specific words or Text in c# on a WPF File. I dont know how to add that attribute because I'm relatively new to programming

I have looked in google and different courses but I can't seem to find anything